# Error when compile Simple Slide at ConTeXt ? (ConTEXt)

Tags: errors, compiling, context

I have problem about compile Simple Slide at ConTeXt, and my MWE like this

```
\usemodule[simpleslides][style=Boxed,color=red]
\setupTitle
  [ title={Title of the presentation},
   author={Name of authors},
     date={Date of presentation},
  ]

\starttext
\placeTitle

\SlideTitle {The first slide}
Write whatever you want.

\SlideTitle {The second slide}
Continue writing.

\stoptext
```

But when compile Simple Slide at ConTeXt and I get error Message like this :

```
Command Line:   C:\context\tex\texmf-mswin\bin\context.exe --synctex=-1 "ss.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\SS


mtx-context     | warning: synctex is enabled
mtx-context     | run 1: luatex --fmt="C:/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luatex/cont-en" --jobname="ss" --lua="C:/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luatex/cont-en.lui" --no-parse-first-line --synctex=-1 --c:currentrun=1 --c:fulljobname="./ss.tex" --c:input="./ss.tex" --c:kindofrun=1 --c:maxnofruns=8 --c:synctex="-1" "cont-yes.mkiv"
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.78.1 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) (rev 4732) 
 \write18 enabled.
(C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-yes.mkiv

ConTeXt  ver: 2014.01.03 00:40 MKIV current  fmt: 2014.1.4  int: english/english

system          > 'cont-new.mkiv' loaded
(C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-new.mkiv)
system          > files > jobname 'ss', input './ss', result 'ss'
fonts           > latin modern fonts are not preloaded
languages       > language 'en' is active
(D:/SS/ss.tex
resolvers       > modules > 'simpleslides' is loaded
(C:/context/tex/texmf-modules/tex/context/third/simpleslides/t-simpleslides.mkiv
loading         > module simpleslides
resolvers       > modules > 'default' is loaded
(C:/context/tex/texmf-modules/tex/context/third/simpleslides/simpleslides-f-default.tex
simpleslides    > loading default font setup
fonts           > bodyfont '17.0pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > preloading latin modern fonts (third stage)
fonts           > typescripts > unknown library 'loc'
(C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/type-otf.mkiv)
fonts           > bodyfont '14pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '16.8pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '13.44pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '15pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '18pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '16pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '19.2pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '15.36pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '20pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '24pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '25pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '30pt' is defined (can better be done global)
{C:/context/tex/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/lm/lm-math.map}{C:/context/tex/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/lm/lm-rm.map}{C:/context/tex/texmf-context/fonts/map/pdftex/context/mkiv-base.map}
fonts           > 'fallback modern ss 17pt' is loaded
)
resolvers       > modules > 'default' is loaded
(C:/context/tex/texmf-modules/tex/context/third/simpleslides/simpleslides-s-default.tex
simpleslides    > loading default style setup
colors          > 'rgb' color space is supported
colors          > 'cmyk' color space is supported
interface       > namespaces > installing namespace 'simpleslidestitle' with settings ' type=module, name=simpleslidestitle, setup=list, style=yes, parent=simpleslidetitle, '
interface       > namespaces > using namespace 'simpleslidestitle' for 'simpleslidestitle'
interface       > namespaces > namespace 'simpleslidestitle' for 'simpleslidestitle' uses parent 'simpleslidetitle'
interface       > namespaces > installing parameter handler for 'simpleslidestitle'
interface       > namespaces > installing parameterhash handler for 'simpleslidestitle'
interface       > namespaces > installing attribute handler for 'simpleslidestitle'
interface       > namespaces > installing setup command for 'simpleslidestitle' (multiple)
interface       > namespaces > installing namespace 'SlideTitle' with settings ' type=module, name=SlideTitle, command=yes, setup=list, style=yes, parent=SlideTitle, '
interface       > namespaces > using namespace 'SlideTitle' for 'SlideTitle'
interface       > namespaces > namespace 'SlideTitle' for 'SlideTitle' uses parent 'SlideTitle'
interface       > namespaces > installing parameter handler for 'SlideTitle'
interface       > namespaces > installing parameterhash handler for 'SlideTitle'
interface       > namespaces > installing attribute handler for 'SlideTitle'
interface       > namespaces > installing definition  command for 'SlideTitle' (single)
interface       > namespaces > installing setup command for 'SlideTitle' (multiple)
)
resolvers       > modules > 'simpleslides-s-Boxed' is loaded
(C:/context/tex/texmf-modules/tex/context/third/simpleslides/simpleslides-s-Boxed.tex
simpleslides    > loading style Boxed
system          > command '\NormalHeight' is already defined
system          > command '\NormalWidth' is already defined
system          > command '\PictureFrameHeight' is already defined
system          > command '\PictureFrameWidth' is already defined
! Undefined control sequence.

system          > tex > error on line 63 in file C:/context/tex/texmf-modules/tex/context/third/simpleslides/simpleslides-s-Boxed.tex: Undefined control sequence ...

53     \define\PictureFrameWidth   {.476\textwidth}
54     
55     %D We define our colorscheme:
56     
57     \definecolor [simpleslides:backgroundcolor]     [s=.75]
58     \definecolor [simpleslides:altbackgroundcolor]  [s=.2]
59     \definecolor [simpleslides:contrastcolor]       [r=.55, g=0, b=.04]
60     \definecolor [simpleslides:variantcolor]     [yellow]
61     \definecolor [simpleslides:itemize:color]       [simpleslides:contrastcolor]
62     
63 >>  \definevisualcounter
64       [simpleslides:squarescounter]
65       [markers]
66       [counter=userpage,
67        distance={(\the\dimexpr\visualcounterparameter{maxwidth})/(max(m-1,1)) - width},
68        path=unitcircle,
69        maxwidth=\textwidth,
70        height=0.5cm,
71        width=0.5cm]
72     
73     \definepalet[visualcounter:markers]

l.63 \definevisualcounter

? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

As a comparison, i adding my MWE with `\usemodule[visualcounter]` like this

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]
\usemodule[simpleslides][style=Boxed]
\setupTitle
  [ title={Simple Slides?},
   author={Hirwanto},
     date={6 Januari 2013},
  ]

\starttext
\placeTitle

\SlideTitle {The first slide}
Write whatever you want.

\SlideTitle {The second slide}
Continue writing.

\stoptext
```

And i still get error Message like this [error simpleslides](https://gist.github.com/Hirwanto/d1c9c47035b10a8ef068)

Any solution to get The Result like this :

[image: Boxed]

Comment: Try adding `\usemodule[visualcounter]` **before** loading `simpleslides`.

Comment: @Aditya, i still get error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in `simpleslides-s-Boxed.tex` style. Until it is fixed upstream, use the following:

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]
\usemodule[simpleslides][style=Boxed]
\setupTitle
  [ title={Simple Slides?},
   author={Hirwanto},
     date={6 Januari 2013},
  ]


\setupvisualcounter
  [simpleslides:squarescounter]
  [
   distance={(\the\dimexpr\visualcounterparameter{maxwidth})/last_counter - width},
  ]

\starttext
\placeTitle

\SlideTitle {The first slide}
Write whatever you want.

\SlideTitle {The second slide}
Continue writing.

\stoptext
```